# If $\big|\int g\varphi \, d\mu\big|\le M\int\lvert\varphi\rvert\,d\mu,$ for all simple functions $\varphi,\,$ then $\lvert g\rvert \le M,$ a. e.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. Suppose $g$ is measurable function such that for some constant $M$ we have $|\int g\phi \, d\mu| \leq M\int |\phi| \, d\mu$ for all simple functions $\phi$. Prove that $|g| \leq M$ almost everywhere. Show that the result is still true if the measure is $\sigma$-finite.

Attempt: I know we have to show that $\{x:|g(x)|>M\}$ is the set of measure zero. But here I choose $M \ge \int|g|d\mu$. Then I have $|\int g\phi \, d\mu|\leq\int|g\phi| \, d\mu=\int |g|d\mu \int|\phi| \, d\mu\leq M\int|\phi| \, d\mu$. By the cancellation I get $|g|\leq \int|g| \, d\mu\leq M$

I think there is something wrong here. I will be grateful if someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean you "choose"? The constant $\;M\;$ is *given*, isn't it? You can't choose it. For one, you could observe that $\;\phi=1\;$ is a simple function so that you're given that $$\left|\int g\,d\mu\right|\le M\mu(X)$$

Comment: I've just wanted to put a lower bound for such constants. May be I should have said the following: Let $A$ be the set of such constants and $B$ be the set of real numbers $\geq \int |g|d\mu$. I choose $M \in A \cap B$

Comment: I think you're still confusing things: first, what "constants"? There is only one, namely $\;M\;$ , which works for **all** simple functions! Second, as as you defined them, it is obvious that $\;A\cap B= A\;$ ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let 
$$
A=\{x\in X :\lvert g(x)\rvert>M\}.
$$
Then $A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n$, where
$$
A_n=\left\{x\in X :\lvert g(x)\rvert>M+\frac{1}{n}\right\}.
$$
It suffices to show that $\mu(A_n)=0$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Let $\varphi_n=\chi_{E_n}\cdot\mathrm{sgn}\,g$; where $\chi_{A_n}$ the characteristic on $A_n$ and $\,\mathrm{sgn}\,g(x)=1$ if $g(x)>0$ and $\,\mathrm{sgn}\,g(x)=-1$ if $g(x)<0$.
Then if $\mu(A_n)>0$, we have that
$$
\left|\int g\varphi_n \,d\mu\,\right| =\int_{A_n} \lvert g\rvert\, d\mu
\ge
\left(M+\frac{1}{n}\right)\mu(A_n)>M\mu(A_n)=M\int_X\lvert\varphi_n\rvert\,d\mu,
$$
which is a contradiction. Thus $\mu(A_n)=0$, for all $n$, and finally $\mu(A)=0$.

Comment: For sigma finite case, it suffices to show that $\mu(A_n)$ is finite. But I couldn't show it. I just know that $A_n$ is the union of sets of finite measure. How can we prove for sigma finite case?Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, @ErginSuer : you're given $\;\mu(X)<\infty\;$ , so what's the problem with sigma of whatever finite cases? Perhaps I'm missing something here.

Comment: Here we replace $\mu(X)<\infty$ by the fact that X is a countable union of measurable sets with finite measure